# Where does main code need to be for a pip installable package?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am still a little confused on how to setup a project to make it pip installable. I have seen some tutorials, but I am not sure which file needs to contain what. Excluding tests, my program has 3 main files:

1. package.py -- this is where main class/methods live.
2. helpers.py -- this is where helper functions live.
3. clf.pkl  -- this is a pickled classifier.

Which one of these need to go into an init file etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all of your code into a python package first such as `your_package` and structure should be like

```
/main_package
    /your_package
        __init__.py
        package.py
        helpers.py
        clf.pkl
    setup.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
```

Check this tutorial for better explanation
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/